# Load font-awesome with jspm

Tags: javascript, jspm

I started investigating jspm and stumbled across this issue.
I seriously search all over Google but could not find a simple answer or example.

How do you load CSS and fonts that come with it?

I tried to do `<script>System.import('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')</script>` but it does not work. It adds .js extension to the url and I get a 404. like this: font-awesome.css.js
I tried `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';` which does not work either.

So, for a jspm packages that contain css and fonts, how do you make them available to my application?

And what about the font files? Do I have to move them manually or get gulp to do it? How do you handle this in your jspm workflow?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Based on the given answer by Joy, I just want to clarify what I want.
Investigating jspm I read about its ability to dynamically load modules (aka es6 module loading). This, I believe, is the crux of jspm. I don't want to bundler every time I change a file! I want to bundle once at the end of the development just before I upload the app to the server. During the development cycle I want jspm to dynamically load my js modules and assets. Otherwise, if bundling is required, I can just use already available (and much faster bundling solutions) like Browseryfy, Webpack. So bundling at every file change is not a solution. With Systemjs and HTTP/2 we should not need to bundle at all ever. And this, I thought, what the jspm was all about.

So can someone tell me if it is possibly to load assets (css, fonts, images) dynamically with jspm the same way it loads js modules? The key word here is dynamically without bundling first. If yes - how?

Answer (score 2):

Before you using `font-awesome` package, you need the `CSS loading plugin` and `CSS build support`.

```
$ jspm install css
$ jspm install npm:clean-css --dev
$ jspm install font-awesome
```

And create the `main.js` file which contains:

> import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css!';

Until now, you have two options that make them available.

(1) The first solution in `index.html` file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main');
    </script>

    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</body>
</html>
```

You don't need to bundle all js file here. Import the `main.js` file only.

(2) Second solution is use `jspm bundle-sfx`

You can build a `build.js` by

```
$ jspm bundle-sfx main.js ./build.js
```

or `gulp` to automatically build the bundle file.

Here is a simple `gulpfile.js` example:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulp_jspm = require('gulp-jspm');

const paths = {
    main: './main.js',
    dest: './dest/'
};

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.main)
      .pipe(gulp_jspm({
          selfExecutingBundle: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});

function reportChange(event){  
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
}

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch([paths.main], ['scripts']).on('change', reportChange);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'scripts']);
```

Now, create a `index.html` file and can test it by `httpster`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./dest/main.bundle.js"></script>

    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</body>
</html>
```

Check the [jspm-cli/docs/plugins.md](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) to get more informations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I understand that bundling is done for production? I gathered from the docs that you can bundle everything in a self executing file. What about development cycle? I cannot re-bundle everything after every css change. Is it possible to import css and make it available without bundling? If not, what is the development workflow? P.S. The css module is installed automatically as dependency when you  install font-awesome, at least that was in my case.

Comment: I have edited the answer. In my development, I use the gulp to automatically build my bundle file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. And I am sorry to drag this but I still don't get the point of it. I updated my question as it was to long to write here.

Comment: you can use `jspm config` file to avoid creating file with `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css!';`.  Once is mapped, you can import it directly into any file.

Answer (score 0):

load it with `css` plugin.

```
jspm install css
jspm install fontawsome=github:FortAwesome/Font-Awesome
```

---

***in the js file***

`import fontawsome from 'fontawsome/css/font-awesome.css!';`

---